# Managing webhooks in Bitbucket Server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-webhook

1. when I configure the web-hooks from bitbucket server. Is there any configuration, I should configured in Jenkins server? eg : special permission for anonymous users..
   Because when I try to test the connection, I am receiving a 403 error. Please see the error details below.

[image]

2. In the webhook, Secret(Optiona) , The string is used to verify data integrity between Bitbucket and your endpoint.  Is there anything I need to configure in my endpoint which is a Jenkins server. How the integrity checking is working here ?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/job/api-xxxxxx/job/stg/job/xxxxxxxxxxx/</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.27.v20200227</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/managing-webhooks-in-bitbucket-server-938025878.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same error. I can suggest you the workaround which will work but I can't assure that it's secure (using Token Based Authentication).

As the 403 status code clearly states that this URL exists but your user isn't authorized to access the URL.

**Below is how you can make it work:**

Navigate to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Select Matrix based security under Authorization and check options below for **Anonymous user**:

```
---------------------------------------------
| User       | Overall | Job                |              
|--------------------------------------------                                           
| Anonymous  | Read    | Read, Workspace &  |
| user       |         | Build              |                                                           
--------------------------------------------
```

and save the changes.

After that Navigate to your job in Jenkins > Configure > Build triggers > And Select "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)"

After selecting this, one text box will appear with tag "**Authentication Token**" where you can generate a token. Enter some text into the text box to generate the token. For example you entered **OathToken**.

Now navigate to Bit Bucket > Repository Settings > Webhook > Edit and enter the URL as follows:

```
JENKINS_URL/view/JenkinsViewName/job/JenkinsJobName/build?token=OathToken
```

In the above URL replace following:

```
JENKINS_URL - With you original Jenkins url (http://Domain/)
JenkinsViewName - With the view name in your Jenkins pipeline
JenkinsJobName - With the job name in your Jenkins pipeline
OathToken - With your original Token value
```

Click on Test connection now and it'll return you 201 status code and it'll trigger the build upon new push in the repository.

Again please consider your security preferences.